# Resources on 3D game programming in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I want to develop 2D/3D games in Android. Can you suggest me good books and/or tutorials on the subject?

Comment: Your title says 3D, your description says 2D - which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what do you want to create? 2D games or 3D games (title and text each say differently)?

2D Programming for games can be done in "Canvas"... you'll find many many tutorials when you google for that...

i.e. https://web.archive.org/web/20200223052828/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html

3D Development basically is done in OpenGL... the thing is that all depends on what you want to create exactly... There are several 3D engines for Gaming on Android, but you could basically do everything on your own with OpenGL...

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience with it but AndEngine looks kewl.   http://code.google.com/p/andengine/ I am looking forward to playing with it when I get some time.  The demo's are impressive.